# VSFTP configuring Virtual users

Tags: ftp

I would like to know what is the best practices or what is the secure way of configuring virtual users via MySQL or Berkeley DB + PAM ???

Comment: i used this guide on my fedora system https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd, i like because i don't need to install mysql for user database

Comment: but then it comes the question which of this is more secure ... using MySQL or DB ?

Comment: DB, because you don't have any extra service running in your server or any tcp port open in your server

Comment: You can run MySQL without a network socket. You are making a false assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try what you asked, and follow the bellow link, SO easily i could run it and use virtual users by Berkeley DB + PAM.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd#Virtual_users_with_TLS.2BAC8-SSL.2BAC8-FTPS_and_a_common_upload_directory_-_Complicated_VSFTPD